# convert lambda to function/method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am trying to understand a program in java which has used lambda to return object into the reference variable of an interface. I want to convert lambda into simple java function, but not sure how to do it.

The program is as follows:-

```
public class AgentLicenseLazyModel extends CoreDataModel<AgentLicenseModel> {

    public AgentLicenseLazyModel(final List<AgentLicenseModel> entities) {
        super(AgentLicenseModel.class, entities, (sortField, sortOrder) -> {
            return new AgentLicenseLazySorter(sortField, sortOrder);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class CoreDataModel<T extends AbstractEntityModel> extends LazyDataModel<T> {

private final Class<T> entityClass;
private final List<T> entities;
private final CoreDataSorterProducer<T> coreDataSorterProducer;

public CoreDataModel(final Class<T> entityClass, final List<T> entities, final CoreDataSorterProducer<T> coreDataSorterProducer) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
    this.entities = entities;
    this.coreDataSorterProducer = coreDataSorterProducer;

    if (entities != null) {
        setRowCount(entities.size());
    }
}
```

How to convert this program into simple java program without use of lambda for learning. Please help.

Edited:
Here is the CoreDataSorterProducer:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CoreDataSorterProducer<T extends AbstractEntityModel> {

    CoreDataSorter<T> produce(String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder);
}
```

Comment: show us `CoreDataSorterProducer` class source

Comment: i added the CoreDataSorterProducer.. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The body of the lambda expression is the implementation of the single abstract method of the `CoreDataSorterProducer<AgentLicenseModel>` interface.

You can replace the lambda expression with an anonymous classs instance that implements `CoreDataSorterProducer<AgentLicenseModel>`.

```
public class AgentLicenseLazyModel extends CoreDataModel<AgentLicenseModel> {
    public AgentLicenseLazyModel(final List<AgentLicenseModel> entities) {
        super(AgentLicenseModel.class, entities, new CoreDataSorterProducer<AgentLicenseModel> () {

            public AgentLicenseLazySorter theMethodName (TheTypeOfSortField sortField, TheTypeOfSortOrder sortOrder) 
            {
                return new AgentLicenseLazySorter(sortField, sortOrder);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that `theMethodName`, `TheTypeOfSortField` and `TheTypeOfSortOrder` should be replaced by the method name of the `CoreDataSorterProducer` interface and the types of its arguments.

Comment: Hi this has been very helpful. Thanks